# Can anyone assist me in converting microseconds since epoch to date format?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to have this nested within an ajax call. I am getting microseconds since epoch as the format on an api response and need it to display in a standard date format.

I found this code for millisecond, can I convert this to microseconds?

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 1486132645639000;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMicro ( millisecondsSinceEpoch );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "HH:mm:ss:SSS" );
String output = formatter.format ( zdt );

System.out.println ( "millisecondsSinceEpoch: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch + " instant: " + instant + " output: " + output );
```

What would be the best way to nest this within this call?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: https://avacmd25.scala.com:44335/ContentManager/api/rest/heartbeats/sequence/'+(item.uuid),
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,
})
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just divide the microseconds value by 1000. now you have milliseconds.

Comment: I suppose that would make sense... Thank you.